# Where can I find and remove Pending Updates and Preview Builds in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-update, disk-space

I have an ACER laptop with 30G of hard drive space, and as I learned after purchasing, most of that in Windows 10 is consumed by System files :)

So I have precious little space to spare, and wonder if I can get rid of the 1.30G of "Pending Updates and Preview Builds" files shown here at bottom:

[image: (listed in temporary files under system > storage)]

Note that I've clicked on View Update Status and nothing there indicates where the files are located or how to remove.

Comment: Start > Run > cleanmgr.exe and hit enter/ok, then on the Disk Cleanup dialog click 'Clean up system files' bottom left. It's more reliable than the new interface, imho.

Comment: I did this (the UI isn't that great) and at first the `Clean System Files` button was present.  I clicked it, it "did it" and then the button was gone.  Checking Storage again, it appeared to have worked.  However sometimes this value fluctuates - I still don't know _WHAT_ it deleted or where it is.  But, positive result :)

Comment: If you no longer want to recieve Insider Preview builds that would require to leave the program.  However, if you are running a Insider Preview build of Windows I wouldn't suggest you do that.  Insider Preview builds expire after a period of time, once they expired, you no longer will be able to use your installation.

Comment: Never been in that program.  So it seems that folder could just be deleted entirely.  I've done a good job with this cleanup so far, and I'll make a backup for it before deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download" would clear the pending updates. That's the easy part.

To install them, you'll need to use a PowerShell Module to get access to the updates via command line and install them manually. Search for PSWindowsUpdate.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as the size of that folder matches the size in the Storage > Temp files value.  I actually did not delete them (as I can live with a few MB, but not so much GB), but used the tip by @spikie_richie in the comment above, that tool seems to have done the job.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command with elevate prompt:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```